# Unable to mount USB media in sagem fast3304 V2 router (busybox v1.01 inside)

Tags: mount, usb, busybox

I have a wireless router that runs `busybox` (V1.0). A media server (`Twonky` Media Version 3.4) running on this router. I would like to use its USB port to mount an external drive containing mutltimedia files.

`hotplug` works very well. It is possible that the media is mounted automatically at a particular location, but I can not find it or mount it.

```
[root @ home]$ shell
BusyBox v1.01 (2010.12.02-16:19+0100) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

# ls -l /sys/block/sda
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan 25 13:46 dev
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan 25 13:46 device -> ../../devices/platform

/vox160-ehci-hcd.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            0 Jan 25 11:35 queue
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan 25 13:46 range
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan 25 13:46 removable
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Jan 25 13:47 sda1
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan 25 13:46 size
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan 25 13:46 stat
--w-------    1 root     root         4096 Jan 25 13:46 uevent

# ls -l /proc/bus/usb
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Jan  1  2000 001
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Jan  1  2000 002
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            0 Jan 25 11:35 devices

# cat /proc/bus/usb/devices
....
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0930 ProdID=6545 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Kingston
S:  Product=DataTraveler 108
S:  SerialNumber=0060E049DF6FEB90B0001934
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
....

# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
31     0      16384 mtdblock0
31     1       1024 mtdblock1
31     2        128 mtdblock2
31     3        128 mtdblock3
31     4        128 mtdblock4
 8     0    3834912 sda
 8     1    3833888 sda1
```

`# mount
  cramfs on /mnt/cramfs type cramfs_mainfs (ro)
  /sys on /sys type sysfs (rw)
  /proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodiratime)
  usbfs on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw)`

Comment: What is exact error message? Did you tried to mount it by hand? And maybe `df` will help you as well as `cat /proc/mounts`. If you have `/dev/sda` node created then most of commands you posted are useless there.

Answer (score 0):

@siblynx, thank you  for you reply. Mounting the media still fails. This is what I get with commands that you have proposed to me:

`# df -h
    Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    cramfs                    3.4M      3.4M         0 100% /mnt/cramfs
    #
    # cat /proc/mounts
    rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
    cramfs /mnt/cramfs cramfs_mainfs ro 0 0
    /sys /sys sysfs rw 0 0
    /proc /proc proc rw,nodiratime 0 0
    usbfs /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw 0 0
    /dev/mtdblock1 /mnt/ffs/A jffs2 rw,sync,noatime 0 0
    #
    # mkdir /media
    #
    # ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media -o rw,sync
    $LogFile indicates unclean shutdown (0, 0)
    Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not supported
    Mount is denied because NTFS is marked to be in use. Choose one action:
    Choice 1: If you have Windows then disconnect the external devices by
              clicking on the 'Safely Remove Hardware' icon in the Windows
              taskbar then shutdown Windows cleanly.
    Choice 2: If you don't have Windows then you can use the 'force' option for
              your own responsibility. For example type on the command line:
                mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media -o force
        Or add the option to the relevant row in the /etc/fstab file:
                /dev/sda1 /media ntfs-3g defaults,force 0 0
    #
    # mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media -o force
    mount: Mounting /dev/sda1 on /media failed: No such device
    #`

Hello everyone, I just found the solution: **safely unmount the device
- Do not remove your drive directly from Windows**,

```
# sfdisk  -l
Disk /dev/sda: 1022 cylinders, 121 heads, 62 sectors/track
Warning: The first partition looks like it was made
  for C/H/S=*/255/63 (instead of 1022/121/62).
For this listing I'll assume that geometry.
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0
   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls   #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      0+    477-    478-  3833888    7  HPFS/NTFS
                end: (c,h,s) expected (477,108,15) found (476,254,63)
/dev/sda2          0       -       0         0    0  Empty
/dev/sda3          0       -       0         0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0         0    0  Empty
# ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media -o rw,sync
/bin/mount: illegal option -- i
#
# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
cramfs                    3.4M      3.4M         0 100% /mnt/cramfs
/dev/sda1                 3.7G     14.8M      3.6G   0% /media
#
# ls -l /media
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan 26 15:27 System Volume Information
# cd /media
#
# mkdir wow
#
# ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan 26 15:27 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan 26 15:30 wow
```